# How to change application properties of war file in Dockerfile

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, hikaricp

I have a jar/war file of Springboot application, it includes the application.properties file (has connection setting to database in Dev environment, placed at the folder src\main\resources, I use hikari datasource). Now, I want to modify the this properties file when create Dockerfile, to build an image for UAT environment. How can I do that ?

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/springboot-docker-mysql.jar springboot-docker-mysql.jar
EXPOSE 8083
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","springboot-docker-mysql.jar"]
```

Here is my properties file:

```
## Spring DATA SOURCE Configurations
#spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false
#spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysql-standalone:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysql-standalone-p-lggjt-mysql.mysql-standalone-p-lggjt.svc.cluster.local:3306/test?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = testuser
spring.datasource.password = testuser@123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

server.port=8083
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:8
VOLUME /tmp
WORKDIR /
ADD target/springboot-docker-mysql.jar springboot-docker-mysql.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","springboot-docker-mysql.jar","--spring.config.additional-location=application.properties"]
```

Change `docker run` command:

```
docker run --name my-app --restart always -it -d -p 8083:8083 -v $PWD/application.properties:/application.properties my-app:v1
```

**NOTE:** `$PWD/application.properties` is your application properties file which you are mounting inside container at `/application.properties` location. Also we made slight change in dockerfile and used `--spring.config.additional-location` option to point to application.properties.

To know more about `--spring.config.additional-location` check [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

Comment: Thank you, can I only need change Dockerfile and the command "Docker build" ? Because I want to create an image with new configuration, then I use Rancher (RKE) to deploy app (I don't use docker run command)

Comment: In that case you can statically copy the application.peroperties inside you docker image. `COPY application.properties /application.properties` and then build the docker image it will have the properties file inside the image.

Comment: If you further want to know how to deploy this on RKE then post another question. I can answer there.